# how to converting mysql into mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

i have the following problem with a login script. at the moment i refresh my site and would like to change mysql into mysqli. i have a working code, that works with mysql like it should to. now i get in trouble with changing that into mysqli, which doesn't work.

here is the original mysql code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $id = $row["id"];   
    session_register('id'); 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

mysql_query("UPDATE tableA SET time=now(), x4=x4 + 1 WHERE id='$id'"); 
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tableB WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) > Date AND ID='$id'"); 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS val FROM tableB WHERE ID='$id'");
        $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        var_dump($count);

    if ($count [val] <xy){  
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableB (Date, ID) VALUES (now(),'$id') ");
        mysql_query("UPDATE tableA SET x7=x7 + 1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

and here is the mysqli version, that wont work and i dont know why:

```
$time = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
        $id = '".$row["id"]."';

$get_id = "SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE x1='".$x1."' AND x2='".$x2."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $get_id);

            if ($result === false) {
                printf("Errormessage 1");
                exit();
                }

            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            $update = "UPDATE tableA SET time=now(), x4=x4 + 1 WHERE id='".$row["id"]."'"; 
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $update);

            if ($result2 === false) {
                printf("Errormessage 2");
                exit();
                }

            $reset = "DELETE FROM tableB WHERE (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) > Date AND ID='".$row["id"]."'";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($db, $reset);

            if ($result3 === false) {
                printf("Errormessage 4");
                exit();
                }

            $count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS val FROM tableB WHERE ID='".$row["id"]."'";
            $result4 = mysqli_query($db, $count);

            if ($result4 === false) {
                printf("Errormessage 5");
                exit();
                }

            $sum = $result4->fetch_assoc($count);
            var_dump($sum);

            if ($count [val] <xy){  

            $insert = "INSERT INTO TableB (Date, ID) VALUES(?,?) ";
            if($query = $db->prepare($insert)){
                $query->bind_param('ss', $time, $id);
                $query->execute();

            $update_x = "UPDATE tableA SET x7=x7 + 1 WHERE id='".$row["id"]."'";
            $result5 = mysqli_query($db, $update_x);

            if ($result5 === false) {
                printf("Errormessage 5");
                exit();
```

Comment: @John I deleted my answer and fixed the quoting to please the syntax highlighter.

Comment: no error will be displayed. it just headers to the goal.

Comment: @John If one of the answers solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted. Leaving your question in place will help other people with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned the actual error but it seems that problem occurs from here:

```
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

you didnot use a loop here like your mysql version of code.

Comment: hello, now i get the error: Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/web775/html/login.php on line 100
NULL what is in that line: $sum = $result4->fetch_assoc($count); but there are 2 parameters?!

Comment: you are referencing it through your result object you dont need to pass any parameters. Why did you pass $count????

Comment: because i thought this is necessary to bind it to an object when working with mysqli. when i start it without referencing, i get the errormessage: array(1) { ["val"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: than it seems to be something else wrong with that or why is it displaying that errormessage. at the moment the tableB is empty that says "0" but why is that not filling with input? i do not understand why it shows that message even when i use a emailadress with faults.

Comment: according to php documentation mysqli_query returns false when your query fails so check your query

Comment: another curious thing is, that when i login there wont be any queries like insert or update in the both tables. but for that case it should print the specific errormessage 1 to 5 if something would be wrong with the queries.

Comment: may be thats because you have used exit statement in your code right after the errormessage so no more script would be execute

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to insert `$time` into what appears to be a `DATETIME` column, based on your old mysql version, but it is improperly formatted.

```
$time = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
```

Based on your use of `NOW()` in the old code, we assume `TableB.Date` to be a `DATETIME` type:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableB (Date, ID) VALUES (now(),'$id') ");
```

So in your new code, since you don't use `NOW()` for the `TableB` insert, you should be creating `$time` as `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
// Should be YYYY-MM-DDD H:i:s for MySQL
$time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

// It gets inserted into TableB here
$insert = "INSERT INTO TableB (Date, ID) VALUES(?,?) ";
        if($query = $db->prepare($insert)){
            $query->bind_param('ss', $time, $id);
            $query->execute();
```

Or, just use MySQL's `NOW()` in the new code unless you have a reason to specify the time in PHP code:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO TableB (Date, ID) VALUES(NOW() ,?) ";
        if($query = $db->prepare($insert)){
            $query->bind_param('s', $id);
            $query->execute();
```

Comment: okay, i changed that to NOW(). it is just necessary to calculate with that time.